# Ext alert not showing correctly in IE

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I am facing some wired problem while using `Ext.Msg.alert()` in Iframes in IE,

(I am working on .Net and Ext js 4.1)

my scenario is, I have one parent iframe which contains a window with two buttons `start` and `cancel`

on click of `start` button two process initiated.

first creates new iframe and shows some information

second creates a hidden iframe and download csv file with `Ext.Msg.alert()` "successfully downloaded" on parent frame

now when I toggle to parent frame I can see `Ext.Msg.alert()` "successfully downloaded" at the center of page in chrome like this.

[image]

but in case of IE it appears at top left of the page with no buttons on alert box
like this
[image]

Is there any way to make it work in IE

Comment: Got the answer, It's an Ext Js problem occurs in version 4.1 they have fixed it in version 4.2.